# IE 100% static div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

Is there a way to make a 100% x 100% static div in the older crappier versions of IE?  If the user is running IE6 for example, I'd like a separate CSS file that only displays a giant black div on the screen and says something like "Your browser is garbage.  You need to upgrade..." or something like that.  A site that comes to mind that uses the same type of display message is http://www.wowhead.com when javascript is turned off.

Comment: How obnoxious. Most IE6 users are not using it by choice, as the IE6 market - whats left of it - is saturated with big corporations imposing this archaic browser on their staff, simply because of the costs involved to upgrade. Being rude and obnoxious about it is not going to make them come back to the site at a later stage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place this on the top of your web-page, and create a custom redirect page for IE6 visitors.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script>
    location.href = "http://www.yourdomain.com/blank_page_for_IE6.html";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```